# Show Grouped Product price in product page view as sum of associated products in grouped product?

Tags: magento2, price, grouped-products, magento2.3.4

```
app/design/frontend/vagwan/moto/Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml
```

How Can I display price sum of associated products in Grouped Product in product page view ? I ve tried this code but is not working.

```
                <tr>
                <?php
                $all = $block->getAssociatedProducts($block->getProductPrice($_item));

                if ($_associatedProducts) {

                    $priceForAll = 0;
                    foreach ($all as $product) {
                        $priceForAll += $product->getPrice();
                    }
                }

                ?>
                <?php echo $priceForAll ?>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
    <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts) : ?>
       <tr>
            <?php
            $priceForAll = 0;
            if ($_associatedProducts) {
                foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item) {
                    $priceForAll += $block->getProductPrice($_item);
                }
            }
            ?>
            <?php echo $priceForAll ?>
        </tr>
     <?php endif; ?>
```